# functioning conflict: carousel, news-ticker, and infoGrid

Tags: jquery, jcarousel, news-ticker

I am trying to mount an infoGrid, taken from **[this site](http://css-tricks.com/grid-accordion-with-jquery/)**
I already have several carousels set up on my page, which i have taken from **[this site](http://ryrych.github.io/rcarousel)**, plus a news ticker, which is from **jquerynewsticker**[DOT]com
Now the problem shows up when I add the infoGrid to my page which already has carousels and news ticker. 
The problem is like, I cannot scroll down to see my infoGrid. Could you please help me solve this problem?
Thanks a lot for your kind help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the css file from the infoGrid into your main css file. It is because you have it separately, and it is trying to call two css files in which you have conflicting elements. delete these lines

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
html, body { height: 100%; overflow: hidden; background: #eee; }
body { font: 14px Georgia, serif; }
```

and include the rest in your main css, everything will be fine then.